# elasticsearch search by special character

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a set of the following phrases: [remix], [18+], etc. How can I make a search by one character, for example "[", to find all these variants ?
Right now I have the following analyzers config:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      { "bigram_analyzer": {
        { "type": "custom",
        { "tokenizer": { "keyword",
        { "filter": [
          { "lowercase",
          "bigram_filter".
        ]
      },
      { "full_text_analyzer": {
        { "type": "custom",
        { "tokenizer": { "ngram_tokenizer",
        { "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
      }
    },
    { "filter": {
      { "bigram_filter": {
        { "type": "edge_ngram",
        { "max_gram": 2
      }
    },
    { "tokenizer": {
      { "ngram_tokenizer": {
        { "type": "ngram",
        { "min_gram": 3,
        { "max_gram": 3,
        { "token_chars": [
          { "letter",
          { "digit",
          { "symbol",
          "punctuation"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping occurs at the java entity level using the spring boot data elasticsearch starter

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly - you want to implement an autocomplete analyzer that will return any term that starts with `[` or any other character. To do so you can create a custom analyzer using ngram autocomplete. Here is an example:

Here is the testing index:

```
PUT /testing-index-v3
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter": {
                "type": "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 15
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "autocomplete_filter"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "term": { 
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the documents input:

```
POST /testing-index-v3/_doc
{
  "term": "[+18]"
}

POST testing-index-v3/_doc
{
  "term": "[remix]"
}

POST testing-index-v3/_doc
{
  "term": "test"
}
```

And finally our search:

```
GET testing-index-v3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "term": {
        "query": "[remi",
        "analyzer": "keyword", 
        "fuzziness": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I chose the keyword tokenizer for the autocomplete filter. I'm using ngram filter with min_gram: 1 and max_gram 15 which means our query will be separated into tokens like this:

`input-query` = `i, in, inp, inpu, input ..` and etc. Separates up to 15 tokens. This is wanted only at indexing time. Looking at the query we specify keyword analyzer as well - this analyzer is for the search time and it hard matches results. Here are some example searches and results:

```
GET testing-index-v3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "term": {
        "query": "[",
        "analyzer": "keyword", 
        "fuzziness": 0
      }
    }
  }
}

result:

    "hits" : [
          {
            "_index" : "testing-index-v3",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "w5c_IHsBGGZ-oIJIi-6n",
            "_score" : 0.7040055,
            "_source" : {
              "term" : "[remix]"
            }
          },
          {
            "_index" : "testing-index-v3",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "xJc_IHsBGGZ-oIJIju7m",
            "_score" : 0.7040055,
            "_source" : {
              "term" : "[+18]"
            }
          }
        ]
```

```
GET testing-index-v3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "term": {
        "query": "[+",
        "analyzer": "keyword", 
        "fuzziness": 0
      }
    }
  }
}

result:

    "hits" : [        
          {
            "_index" : "testing-index-v3",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "xJc_IHsBGGZ-oIJIju7m",
            "_score" : 0.7040055,
            "_source" : {
              "term" : "[+18]"
            }
          }
        ]
```

Hope this answer helps you. Good luck with your adventures with elasticsearch!